# Kill rosrun gracefully

Tags: rosrun, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am running a rosrun command to generate and publish messages continuously from a node X. But I am not able to gracefully kill the session. I am currently closing the terminal in order to stop the task.

Kindly let me know if the below 2 approaches are correct and how to implement it.

1. Open a new terminal and kill the node X
2. Ctrl+C to stop the the publishing of messages and return to the terminal (This is what I am actually looking for)

Code Snippet;

```
     while(ros :: ok)
     {
         ros_time = ros:Time::now();
         publish the message;
         update the message;
         ros::SpinOnce();
      }
```

I would create a package and then run rosrun

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295116/kill-rosrun-gracefully/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-23**:
It's likely the node you cannot shutdown is not correctly programmed. Common cause: not checking `ros::ok()` in your while-loop. Please show us some code of the node or check it yourself.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-23**:
Note btw: even if things were working correctly, you'd not be "killing rosrun", but would be shutting down the node.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-23**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for the response... code snippet does have ros::ok() condition in while loop...
Is there a way I can use Ctrl+C to terminate the rosrun .?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-23**:
Then please show your code, otherwise we can only guess why things don't work the way they should.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-26**:
@gvdhoorn I was able to stop the node by killing it in another terminal.. however I need to know how can I use Ctrl+C to come out of terminal in this case..  I update the code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this was already covered in your other question (#q294951), but this:

```
while(ros :: ok)
```

is not correct.

It should be: `ros::ok()`. It's a function, not a variable.

What you have now probably checks a function pointer, which will evaluate to `true`, hence making your while-loop equivalent to `while (true)`.

In addition: you don't have a `ros::Rate` with a `rate.sleep()` in there anywhere. Adding one will probably help.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-26**:
@gvdhoorn ros:ok() worked like a champ.. Now I am able to Ctrl+C to come out of the terminal.. That small mistake was ruining my day...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-26**:
If you haven't, do add the `ros::Rate`. If you don't add it, your little node will be using 100% cpu even when it's doing nothing.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-06-26**:
@gvdhoorn thank you.. Yep.. I have added the ros::Rate and sleep.rate()..